# In Ember automatically route application to error route if template promise returns error

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Given a route it is easy enough to get Ember to navigate to an error route if the model promise rejects. Currently I have the simple method of having an `error.hbs` and `/routes/error.js`, and if the model promise errors it loads the error page.

I have a situation where the model resolves fine, but one of its relationships does not. This relationship is used in the routes template e.g.

```
{{#each model.addresses as |address id|}}
  {{address.line1}}
{{/each}}
```

So `myurl.com/api/addresses/1` returns a 500 error. I see this in the console window, but Ember does not automatically transition to the error page. How can I get it to do this for all promises that reject as a result of a template requesting more data?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to return `RSVP.Promise` in route `model()` which loads all data (also relationships instead of lazy loading them later by template) and rejects if any of asynchronous requests fail.

Comment: Good suggestion - although a pain to make sure the dev team does everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Ember generates the error pages by it self if im not wrong, if ember depends on an DS.error object for the transition you have to fulfill the requirements in order to get Ember to recognize an valid error, in Ember 2.x the error code MUST be 422 and has to follow jsonapi http://jsonapi.org/format/#errors-processing

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter what the error code is (tested with 422 as well as 500). If the promise is coming from a relationship that the template loads and it returns 422 or 500 it does not transition to an error page.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up a long post on using Route error substates here -> https://pixelhandler.com/posts/emberjs-handling-failure-using-route-error-substates

Answer (score 0):

So ultimately, error handling happens as the result of knowing "what broke" and "who owns the fact that it broke". Generally, if X asked for Y and Y fails, its X's job to display the error. In that example, if FooRoute triggers an ajax, and it fails, FooRoute more or less should handle the error.

But when it comes to the template causing fetches, it actually becomes the responsibility of the template.

One thing one can do is, actually bind to the various boolean properties representing the async operation on the PromiseProxy (in your case, `model.addresses`). The properties are as follows

- isPending - ongoing work is happening
- isFulfilled - it is done, and succeeded
- isRejected - it is done, but failed
- isSettled, - it is done (failed or succeeded)

using these flags could be as follows

```
{{#if model.addresses.isPending}}
   loading...
{{else if mode.addresses.isRejected}}
  Sorry something went wrong, {{model.addresses.reason.message}}
{{else}}
  {{#each model.addresses as |address| }}
     ...
  {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0):

When loading data for a page, I like to ask myself, *what data is **critical** to show?* That is, if there are three sections on the page -- say backed by `foo`, `foo.bars`, and `foo.baz` -- are all three sections of highest priority? Or can I let one of them fail and show the other two? Let's assume that without either `foo` or `foo.bars`, we show an error page, but `foo.baz` is optional. In that case, I would write that as

```
// controller:foo
model(params) {
  return this.get('store').find('foo', params.id);
},
afterModel(foo) {
  return foo.get('bars'); // block on foo.bars fetch
}
```

Then I might have a `{{foo-baz}}` component that renders *Loading...* at first, then fetches `foo.baz` in the background and shows the full content later.